# How to make multitenancy with pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I'm using pentaho EE 6.1, and I'd like to setup an data source specific for an user, I'v seen in this link https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.1/0R0/070/Multi-Tenancy
but I don't undersand how to make it.
Some help please.

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear.
But i had this same issue sometime back and i am sharing my research and understanding.
In Data integration we have option called **parameterised connection** and in this way you can achieve multitenancy but due to **pentaho architecture** of bi server **we can't achieve** the same in **bi server**.
you can achieve this in bi server through **stored procedure** this is one of the way.